# How to write json data(nested array) to file in one line format with Python?

Tags: python, json, file

I want to write json data to file, my expect as below, the nested array is very long

```
{
  "test1": {
    "key1": [[0, 40], [2, 42], [4, 44], [6, 46], [8, 48], [10, 50], [12, 52],......],
    "key2": [[1, 41], [3, 43], [5, 45], [7, 47], [9, 49], [11, 51], [13, 53],......]
  },
  "test2": {
    "key1": [[0, 52], [1, 53], [2, 54], [3, 55], [4, 56], [5, 57], [6, 58],......],
    "key2": [[26, 78], [27, 79], [28, 80], [29, 81], [30, 82], [31, 83],......]
  }
}
```

But when I use json.dump to write file, there are a lot of lines

```
with open("test.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(result, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

```
{
  "test1": {
    "key1": [
      [
        0,
        40
      ],
      [
        2,
        42
      ],
      [
        4,
        44
      ],
      [
        6,
        46
      ],
      [
        8,
        48
      ],
      [
      ...
      ...
```

Is there any way can make these arraies in one line?

Comment: I think is does not change the size of your file if it is in one line or not

Comment: Thanks, I used the way from "Write two-dimensional list to JSON file", it works

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test.json", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(result))
```